# Show/Hide an item of array.map() reactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs

When I Click on "Menu 1", all the subMenus are also displayed
but what I want is to show/hide only the selected sunMenu of an item.
(i.e)if I click on "Menu 2" show only "SubMenu 3"
My Code:

```
    this.state = {
      menu: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "Menu 1",
          subMenu: [
            {
              id: 3,
              title: "SubMenu 1"
            },
            {
              id: 4,
              title: "SubMenu 2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Menu 2",
          subMenu: [
            {
              id: 5,
              title: "SubMenu 3"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      isHidden: true
    };
  }
  toggleHidden = () =>
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ isHidden: !prevState.isHidden }));


    return (
      <div>
        {menu.map((m) => (
          <div>
            <p onClick={this.toggleHidden}>{m.title}</p>

            {!this.state.isHidden &&
              m.subMenu.map((s) => (
                <div>
                  <p>{s.title}</p>
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Working Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-sinoussi-4rgci?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
{menu.map((m) => (
          <div>
            <p onClick={this.toggleHidden}>{m.title}</p>

            {!this.state.isHidden &&
              m.subMenu.map((s) => (
                <div>
                  <p>{s.title}</p>
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        ))}
```

you should map every element od `menu` to a Comonent whose state has `isHidden` field

Now you have 1 state for all submenus

Answer (score -1):

`const [selected , setSelected]  = useState(false)`

you can create a state that tells when a sub-menu is selected. then add to each element a `selected : {slected}` property.

then instead of using `m.subMenu.map` you should use `m.subMenu.filter` and return all elements that have `selected` set to `true`

for more info about `filter`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter